# How to make FlatList footer stretch to bottom?

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app with a FlatList. The FlatList usually longer than the screen so this isn't an issue but when someone searches the flat list gets smaller and doesn't fill the whole screen leaving the background to show below it. How can I get the FlatList footer to fill that bottom part on search? I've tried flex a bit and can't get it working. If anybody knows the code for this that would be super helpful. I'm sure it's not hard, I'm just stuck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set the style as `style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}` (recommended)

You can also use React Native Dimensions and get the screen height and set it as your list height. Something like this:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
...
const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
...
style={{ height }}
...
```

Hope it helps.